# Why does Agresti define the natural exponential family this way?

Tags: categorical-data, estimators

I am reading through Agresti's Categorical Data Analysis. And in section 4.1.1 he defines the natural exponential family as: $f(y_i;\theta_i) = a(\theta_i)b(y_i)*exp(y_iQ(\theta_i))$ Why is this different from the common definitions I find after a short google of "natural exponential family." For instance; the definition on Wikipedia is stated as $f_X(x|\theta) = h(x) exp(\eta(\theta)T(x)-A(\theta))$. But the article goes no further to describe what $\eta(\theta)$ or $A(\theta)$ are defined to represent. I understand that $T(x)$ to be an estimator but that is about where my knowledge ends, quite literally with "that is an estimator".

I have an undergrad level understanding of statistics. So some of this text is a bit beyond my knowledge. In fact it may even help to point out a textbook or some additional material that may help resolve some of the gaps in my knowledge regarding statistics. My 'unknown unknowns'.

Comment: There may be less going on here than you suspect, because (fortunately) all you need is a high school knowledge of logarithms: that will suffice to identify all corresponding parts of the two formulas.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. It made some more sense when I examined the function within the context of a Poisson distribution. Also, thank you for taking the time to comment. I read a bit of your profile and web page.